# MySQL: таблица со списком регулярных выражений. Поиск выражения, соответствующего фразе

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

**Дано:**

Таблица, в которой занесены некоторые регулярные выражения, к примеру:

```
id  reg
1   %BC_
2   __AC_
3   %FC
... и т.д.
```

**Требуется:**

Найти все «id», регулярные выражения которых подходят под конкретную фразу.

К примеру, есть код: «**DEACY**», которому соответствует (в данном примере) только строка №2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем примере не регулярные выражения, а маски поиска. Запрос достаточно простой, если остальные "регулярные выражения" подобны этому:

```
SELECT * 
FROM regulars
WHERE 'DEACY' LIKE reg;
```

Comment: То, что доктор прописал! Благодарю!